# How do I access an internal link with Selenium that seems restricted

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to fetch data from [nj.58.com](https://nj.58.com) using selenium. I can access the homepapage and some internal links. While navigating through the links, I noticed that the website sees me as a web crawler when I visit a specific url; even if I interact with the links as a human.

I have built my selenium script to a point but I'm stock because the sites throws antibot response back at me.

Here is what I've done:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time
import pandas as pd


driver = uc.Chrome()
website = 'https://nj.58.com/'


driver.get(website)
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.maximize_window()

switch_city = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#commonTopbar_ipconfig > a"))).click()

city_location = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#selector-search-input')))

city_location.clear()
city_location.send_keys('南京' + Keys.RETURN)

keyword = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#keyword')))

keyword.clear()
keyword.send_keys('"废纸回收"')
time.sleep(2)

search_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#searchbtn')))
search_btn.click()
```

When I click on *search_btn*, I'm expecting to see a list of items that I'm interested in. But instead it sees me as a web crawler at this variable position (*search_btn*) even before using the selenium.

How can I bypass this antibot/antihuman detection at point when I click on *search_btn*?

Comment: We cannot answer this without knowing **how** the site detects you. You could wait longer. You could add `User-Agent` HTTP header to the site requests. You could emulate a random mouse movement on the page. But these are all temporary solutions.

Comment: @OneCricketeer The response I get is *The system detects that you are suspected of using a web crawler to visit this website, please uninstall and delete it before visiting, ip: 10....*

Comment: Like I said, we cannot know how the site detects you. You'll need to figure that out in order to bypass it